# Get all products from a feed with API Shopping Content python library

Tags: google-shopping-api

Is it possible to get all the products from one GMC feed with the API Shopping Content python library.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import googleapiclient.discovery

# Remplacez ces valeurs par les informations de votre projet et de vos identifiants
service_account_file = 'XXX'
merchant_id = 'XXX'
feed_id = 'XXX'

# Autorisez l'accès avec le fichier de clé de service
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    service_account_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/content']
)

# Initialisez l'API Shopping Content
content = googleapiclient.discovery.build('content', 'v2.1', credentials=credentials)

# Récupérez tous les produits du feed
request = content.products().list(merchantId=merchant_id)
response = request.execute()

# Parcourez les produits
if 'resources' in response:
    products = response['resources']
    for product in products:
        #print(products)
        if 'offerId' in product and feed_id in product['offerId']:
            print(f"ID du produit : {product['offerId']}")
            print(f"Titre du produit : {product['title']}")
            print(f"État du produit : {product['contentLanguage']}")
            print("----------")

# Gérez les erreurs
if 'errors' in response:
    for error in response['errors']:
        print(f"Erreur : {error['message']}")
```

I wanted to add a condition on the feed through the line
`request = content.products().list(merchantId=merchant_id)`
with something like this
`request = content.products().list(merchantId=merchant_id, feedId=feed_id)`

But it's not working. Maybe it's through the feed Service that I could achieve it but I can't find anything online that could help me.

Thank you for your help !